# How do I find the right ubuntu kernel for an i686 CPU?

Tags: boot, kernel, cpu

I burned a copy of Ubuntu to dvd, I went to install it on an Acer Aspire 5610z which had vista. I removed vista and put xp on it about 3 or 4 years ago. My problem is that I now have a black screen with the following two lines of text at the top:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
>
> Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU

My question is how and where do I find a version of Ubuntu that will work with my CPU?

Answer (score 0):

There exist several possible options to handle this problem. Since your reputation is low I'll assume you're not very experienced and this solution is quite easy. Go here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/15.04/release/ and download the 32 bit version. Those are the files with '386' as part of the name. It is highly likely that the 32 bit version will run on your system without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'i386' version of the kernel instead of 'amd64'. Sorry to tell you but you will have to get another copy of Ubuntu, this time with i386 architecture. i386 is compatible with i486, i586 and i686, like in your case.